# How to keep the file size of a stream small and have manycam show a live picture?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, streaming, http-live-streaming

I am using this command

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k.mov" "C:\wamp\www\streaming.mjpeg"
```

to stream to "C:\wamp\www\streaming.mjpeg". Then I am using `SimpleHTTPServer` to create a web server for this folder.

Then I am pointing [ManyCam's](https://manycam.com/) ip camera to the address of the file on the web server

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/streaming.mjpeg
```

And select it in `ManyCam`.

As a result ffmpeg creates a file that gets bigger and bigger and `ManyCam` shows an endless time-lapsed loop of what the camera records or recorded minutes ago.

How to keep the file size small and have `ManyCam` show a live video feed?